# ODE with Holder drift - Cauchy-Peano theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the following ODE:
$$
x'(t)=b(x(t)),\quad  x(0)=x_0.
$$
If $b$ is bounded and Holder continuous, then the Cauchy-Peano theorem ensures that there exists a solution to the above equation (but in general not unique). The question is:

is it possible that there always exists a solution $x_t(x_0)$ which depends Lipschitz continuous in $x_0$? Or $x_0\to x_t(x_0)$ is one-to-one?

Many thanks for the answers!

Comment: The same question was answered in MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296369/ode-with-holder-drift-cauchy-peano-theorem